# Two different ways to return a value from an ES6 arrow function - Why are they different? What's going on here?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Slightly silly question, but I've been working with a lot of JS recently and have found myself pulling values from arrow functions in two different ways.

One is like this:

```js
let random_value = /* whatever */

// One way to test the value and save the result
let value = (myValue => {
    if(random_value > 50) {
        myValue("Bigger than 50");
    } else {
        myValue("Smaller than 50");
    }
});

// Another way to test the value and save the result
let value_2 = (() => {
    if(random_value > 50) {
        return "Bigger than 50"
    } else {
        return "Smaller than 50"
    }
})();
```

Can someone explain the subtle differences here?
Is one of these methods the "proper" way to do this?

I'm just trying to figure out what's going on. Why do both work?

Thanks all.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you're asking. These are 2 completely different bits of code that bear little relation to each other. The first is a function that takes a function argument and calls it with the value 100, but doesn't return anything. The second, `value_2`, is just a complex way of writing the value `100` (via an "immediately invoked function expression"). I don't know what the actual question is and which piece of syntax you are unsure about.

Comment: you can do `let value = 100` it works fine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is `myValue`? Edit: Also, given that `value` is a function, how are you calling `value`?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly and implicitly return a value from an arrow function.

If your code contains only one line you can return implicit return value

```
const fn = arg => arg
```

When your code contains more than one line you return explicit return value

```
const fn = arg => {
 Do something
 return arg
}
```

Hope it might help you

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies to the question.

Comment: Thanks! I made an edit based on some earlier comments about this question. However, after reading your answer, am I right in thinking the first method (post edit) would not work then? Or at least not save the string to the variable "value" like I'd expect it to?

Comment: Yea @rusty_vibess as you're not returning anything on first function, you'd simply get undefined save on your "value" variables. You have to explicitly return the value.